# wpf - on select item from nested listview also select parent listview

Tags: wpf

I have a listview containing a text block and another list.
I want when the user clicks on a nested listviewitem the parent listviewitem to be also selected.
Example:
[image]

In the above image Lista2 (parent list item) is selected.
The user clicks on Linia6 from Lista1 to select it. When Linia6 from Lista1  (nested list item) is selected, also Lista1 (parent list item) to be selected.

Also if it is possible to do this on code behind, not XAML

My code

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding listsToDisplay}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Width="200">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Width="250"  Text="{Binding listName}"></TextBlock>
                        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding listContent}">
                        </ListView>
                    </StackPanel>

                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Can you describe some more details about the desired selection behavior? From your picture it looks as if `Lista1.Linia6` was selected last, but you write it should also select `Lista2`, so I don't really understand what you want.

Comment: Made an edit to the post and added this information: In the above image Lista2 (parent list item) is selected. The user clicks on Linia6 from Lista1 to select it. When Linia6 from Lista1 (nested list item) is selected, also Lista1 (parent list item) to be selected.

Comment: And should `Lista2.Linia4` be deselected (basically, having only one selection across all nested lists)?

Comment: did not thought about this part, it is not necessary although it would be a good practice and interesting for me ti know how to do this

Comment: Well, you should think about using a `TreeView` with `HierarchicalDataTemplate` instead of nested `ListView`.

Comment: after working more on the app I have seen that I need to do this on code behind (I am in a user control so no break MVVM). the solution of using in wpf a TreeView is not possible for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `SelectedItem` property of the nested `ListView` is not used by other means, you can bind it to `ListViewItem.IsSelected` of it's parent, using a converter. Note, the `SelectionMode="Single"` on the parent listview is important to avoid double-selection by the converter.

```
<Grid x:Name="grid1">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:SelectedItemTransferConverter x:Key="ItemSelectedConverter"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding listsToDisplay}" SelectionMode="Single">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding listName}"/>
                    <ListView
                        ItemsSource="{Binding listContent}"
                        SelectedItem="{Binding IsSelected,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}},Converter={StaticResource ItemSelectedConverter}}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

The converter code:

```
public class SelectedItemTransferConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is bool || value is bool?)
        {
            if ((bool?)value == false)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (targetType == typeof(bool) || targetType == typeof(bool?))
        {
            return value != null;
        }
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```